# File Selection in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, directory

I am very new to Qt but am trying to use it for a very simple file selection UI.  I would really like to implement an interface like a software install (tree with checks and squares designating the entire folder, part of the folder, and then checks for individual files) for the entire drive tree.  Does anyone know if there is a way to do this in Qt?  I have also been trying to use just the QTreeView, but keep getting the error that 
  "ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'QModelIndex' with no type"

Does anyone know how to fix this?

In short, I am looking for any way to list the entire directory, select multiple parts, and return the list of selected files.

Comment: Show the line of source with the error.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use QFileDialog for that: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html.